# Show <span> beside <select>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span>` and a `<select>`. In the below code the `<span>` appears above the `<select>` whereas **I want to show `<span>` first and the `<select>` should appear next to it.**

```css
.requiredStar {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.input-block-level {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12"> 
    <span class="requiredStar">*</span>
    <select class="input-block-level">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I show the `<select>` next to `<span>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution, adding `display:flex;` on the `.span12` container:

```css
.requiredStar {
  color: #FF0000;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.input-block-level {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/** added this CSS code */
div.span12 {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12"> 
    <span class="requiredStar">*</span>
    <select class="input-block-level">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you want to show the asterisk after the `<select>`? Move it behind the `<select>` element. You can also use `padding-top` and `padding-right` to control the position of the asterisk.

Comment: is there anyway to do without modifying the bootstrap span12,  probably by modifying requiredStar class. this star appears beside each input element

Comment: Is there any way i can add some spacing and bring the star little below.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the select has width: 100% and `display: block`. Block level elements extend the whole width of their individual rows.

Reduce the width of the select and set the display to `inline` or `inline-block`

```css
.requiredStar {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.input-block-level {
  display: inline;
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <span class="requiredStar">*</span>
    <select class="input-block-level">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```